# JSON-c library mapping to python json modules

Tags: python, c, json, serialization

I've wrote simple application to send message from client to server in python and I've used json data interchange language for formatting. 
This application is works fine.

Now I've re-implemented client application in C programming language but server in python language only.

I'm using json-c library from [here](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) for json functions in client application.

I'm sending one msg(with serialization done) to server , at server side while deserialization its giving error.
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 0: invalid start byte"

I don't know what above error is and i have some other doubts also.

How to insert json object within object without serialization using json-c library?? (For this i tried converting json object to json string but output of object is serialized one but in case of python when we call dump/dumps that time only it will serialize the object otherwise it will just insert plain object into object).

Is the level of serialization called in my client application and same level of deserialization in server will give me the proper output??(because client using json-c and server using marshal/pickle modules)

Any suggestion are helpful.

Comment: Could you add code samples showing the serialization and de-serialization?

Comment: In client application: 
 json_object *Json_msg_data;
 json_msg_data = json_object_new_object();
 json_object_object_add(Json_msg_data, "SL", json_object_new_string(Number));
 json_object_object_add(Json_msg_data, "MSG", json_object_new_string(MSG));
json_object_to_json_string(json_msg_data); // serialization 
In Server;
Receiving packets through sockets and doing deserialization of packet
json.loads( msg );